# Create a QML plugin to run system commands?

Tags: c++, c, plugins, qml

I'd like to run commands and show the output in quite a few Ubuntu Touch apps I'd like to create, so therefore I need to create a plugin for QML in C/C++(?) with this functionality.

The thing is that I don't know anything about C/C++, nor do I really want to learn it. However I do need it now and I need help to get going.

How would I create this plugin? Where do I start?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from Joseph Mills: https://code.launchpad.net/~josephjamesmills/+junk/launchTotem

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap QProcess which allows you to run any shell command.

Check this [out](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#details)

And for Ubuntu touch you can use wizard for qml plugins. Its quite easy actually.

Comment: Thank you, but I just don't understand any of the C/C++ code. In which file should I paste it, and how do I import into my app, and what about compilation?
What is this Wizard? The one in QtCreator?

Answer (score 0):

You shall use **PlasmaCore.DataSource** with the engine "**executable**", as in this [example](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-lib/blob/d0b3329cb186b4cf6d412b438406ee3ec4190bcc/package/contents/ui/lib/AppletVersion.qml#L15).

Mind that the call is **asynchronous**. Hence the command sends a **signal** when it finishes, and a different part of the code picks the signal and continues with the next step you want to perform.